# Host name Configuration on IIS7

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, iis-7, hostname, antiforgerytoken

Facing issue after applying host name. Application is working fine without the host name. Once i provide the host name for application in Bindings some of the functionality stops working like export to excel,edit.
Giving exception for [ValidateAntiForgeryToken] "The required anti-forgery cookie "__RequestVerificationToken" is not present" even it is there in controller and view. It is working absolutely fine without DNS name.

Application is created in mvc4  with Entity Framework .

Any help will be grateful...

Comment: Please specify in more details. Is is working with localhost hostname? And what is the exact host name it is not working with?

Comment: Yes it is working with localhost hostname. i am providing the DNS name applicationname_dev.